# Gutenberg Create Custom Block with array of TextControls

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

i created a gutenberg-block on which you can select images from the media-gallery and write a name to the image.

My goal is that you can write a little more information.

The block is server-rendered to create vue.js code for the frontend.
The TextControl is generated in a loop dependent on the images-array (attribute) and store its values with an onchange event in the texts-array (also an attribute).

Everything works, but after every character i type, the script is hanging 3 seconds.
What am i doing wrong?

I expected that to work without hanging up:

Block registration:

```
   register_block_type(__DIR__ . '/custom-blocks/adelt-team/build', [
        'render_callback' => function ($attributes, $content) {

            global $field;
            $field['id'] = $attributes['blockId'];
            ob_start();

            get_template_part("template-parts/team",null,$attributes);;
            return ob_get_clean();

        },
    ]);
```

Edit.JS (i have two attributes (images and texts):

```
/**
 * React hook that is used to mark the block wrapper element.
 * It provides all the necessary props like the class name.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-block-editor/#useblockprops
 */
import {useBlockProps} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

import {MediaPlaceholder} from "@wordpress/block-editor";

import {BlockIcon} from "@wordpress/block-editor"

import {BlockControls} from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import {ToolbarButton, ToolbarGroup} from "@wordpress/components";
import {MediaUpload, MediaUploadCheck} from "@wordpress/block-editor";

import {InspectorControls} from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import {TextControl} from "@wordpress/components";

import {useState} from '@wordpress/element';


/**
 * Lets webpack process CSS, SASS or SCSS files referenced in JavaScript files.
 * Those files can contain any CSS code that gets applied to the editor.
 *
 * @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/scripts#using-css
 */
import './editor.scss';

/**
 * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the
 * editor. This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#edit
 *
 * @return {WPElement} Element to render.
 */
// src/edit.js
export default function Edit(props) {


    const hasImages = props.attributes.images.length > 0;

    //Following lines are required to save a unique block-id for the gallery. Used in PHP as field id.
    const {attributes, setAttributes, clientId} = props;
    const {blockId} = attributes;

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!blockId) {
            setAttributes({blockId: clientId});
        }
    }, []);

    console.log("flo", props.attributes);

    return (
        <>
            <InspectorControls>

            </InspectorControls>
            <BlockControls>
                <ToolbarGroup>
                    <MediaUploadCheck>
                        <MediaUpload
                            multiple
                            gallery
                            addToGallery={true}
                            onSelect={(newImages) =>
                                props.setAttributes({images: newImages})}
                            allowedTypes={["image"]}
                            value={props.attributes.images.map((image) => image.id)}
                            render={({open}) => (
                                <ToolbarButton onClick={open}>
                                    {"Galerie bearbeiten"}
                                </ToolbarButton>)}
                        />
                    </MediaUploadCheck>
                </ToolbarGroup>
            </BlockControls>
            <div {...useBlockProps()}>
                {hasImages && (
                    <figure className="scrollable-gallery-inner-container">

                        {props.attributes.images.map((image, index) => (
                            <div>
                                <img key={index} src={image.url}/>


                                <TextControl
                                    label="Name"
                                    value={props.attributes.texts[index] ? props.attributes.texts[index] : index}
                                    onChange={(value) => {
                                        //I think, here is the Problem
                                        if (value != props.attributes.texts[index]) {
                                            var texts = props.attributes.texts;
                                            texts[index] = value;

                                            props.setAttributes({texts: texts});
                                        }
                                    }}
                                />
                                <span>{image.alt}</span>

                            </div>


                        ))}
                    </figure>
                )}
                {!hasImages && (
                    <MediaPlaceholder
                        multiple
                        gallery
                        icon={<BlockIcon icon="format-gallery"/>}
                        labels={{
                            title: "Team",
                            instructions: "Erzeuge einen Slider des Teams.",
                        }}
                        onSelect={(newImages) => props.setAttributes({images: newImages})}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Thank you!